# Publish option in the newly updated MobileMe calendars disappears, how do I fix it?

Tags: apple-ical, mobileme

Yesterday I updated my MobileMe calendars to the new format and than I noticed that the Publish option has disappeared from my iCal calendars. All my iCal calendars now show up under my MobileMe heading on the left hand side, perhaps because they are being shared with another computer via MobileMe. The only option under the Calendar menu now is Share Calendar.

I need to be able to send the URL for one of my iCal calendars so that anyone with a browser can see it. The webcal URL to subscribe to the calendar is useless. It used to also show the option to look at the calendar using the iCal URL, but that option is now gone.

Anyone knows if it's still possible and how to do it?

Comment: i've just discovered the same issue.  I'm extremely dependenty on this - lets hope someone comes up with the answer soon.  I feel you are right - it disappeared when I switched to the new mobileme format.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible, but I've only done it via the me.com website, not from iCal, and I don't have my Mac with me to check it in iCal.

Login to me.com and switch to the Calendar view (click the cloud at the top left and then click Calendar.)

Click the the "Share Calendar" circular button to the right of the calendar you wish to share, and when a dialog pops up, select "Public Calendar" and click "Share."

The dialog will update with an ics URL that you can copy or email to yourself and others to give them read-only access to your calendar.